# Uploading an edited preferences plist to a non-jailbroken iPhone running iOS 7.0

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to change a setting in one of my iOS device's plists, and upload it to the device **without doing a full restore from backup**.

1. How can I extract the file from an unencrypted backup on my Mac?
2. How can I upload the modified file to my device?

Comment: Where is the file located? A global preference file, or a preference file for an app?

Comment: It's a global preference file under the SystemPreferences domain. I can extract it from my backup with `AppleMobileBackup --domain SystemPreferencesDomain`, but I don't know what to do with it from there.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with i fun box for mac. Go here http://i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/

Comment: Care to explain this answer a bit more?